# Yeast conservation after broken packaging

Tags: yeast

I broke up the wyeast American ale pack, but I can not make beer today, how long can I wait before the yeast die?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The yeast don't die for many months - some would say years. If you keep the re-sealed pack in the fridge it will be good for some weeks yet and with a little care will be good for some months.

Comment: even if the packaging is swelled?

Comment: Yes, put it in the fridge and use it within the next few days and you should be OK. Yeast reduces in activity as the temperature falls so it will be practically dormant in the fridge and has sufficient nutrients in the pack to keep it going for a day or two.If the pack gets very inflated, piece it with a clean needle, allow the pressure to drop then reseal with tape.